# How to play dynamic sounds in XNA?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Is it possible to dynanmically generate sounds with XNA C# code?

I looked into this some time ago when XNA was first released.  At that time it was only possible to playback sound resources included in the compiled code.

Have there been any changes or new features added since XNA 1.0 that would allow an XNA application to generate and playback audio on the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

XNA 4.0 added support for dynamic audio that allows you to:

- Create a regular immutable sound
  effect from a raw buffer using the [SoundEffect.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream(XNAGameStudio.40).aspx) method.
- Create a 
  [DynamicSoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.dynamicsoundeffectinstance.aspx) object then modify the audio data of this new
  streaming sound effect object
  dynamically.

Read more in the blog entry [What’s “Dynamic” about this SoundEffectInstance?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashtat/archive/2010/09/08/what-s-dynamic-about-this-soundeffectinstance-part-1.aspx) and in the AppHub article [Dynamic Audio](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/dynamic_audio).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in XNA with DirectSound.  Here's a link with code that seems to do what you want:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/40361.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends how dynamic you want to get. I know that XACT will let you change pitch and such, which, when combined with using cues in a programmatic fashion, can give some nice results.

<strike>If you want to generate your own waveform, you're out of luck.</strike> There's always the option of dropping below the framework and doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect you are right. I would want to do this on xbox/zune/wp7 so unfortunately going DirectSound/outside the framework isn't much of a option.