# C#/XNA - Playing a generated tone based on frequency

Tags: c#, xna

I'm writing a little app that's pretty much a sequencer (8 bit synths) I have a formula which converts a note to its corresponding frequency:

```
private float returnFrequency(Note note)
{
    return (float)(440 * Math.Pow(TwoToTheTwelfthRoot, (note.SemitonesFromC0 - 57)));
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is play a generated tone (sine, square, saw, etc) with this frequency, so it's audible through the speakers. Does XNA have any support for this? Or would I have to use an additional library?

I do not want to import 80+ samples of a sine wave at different frequencies through the Content Pipeline just so I could play tones with different frequencies.

Comment: I think this SO question asks and answers the same underlying question. [How to play dynamic sounds in XNA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032450/how-to-play-dynamic-sounds-in-xna)

Comment: I found a nice little article about it already on Google, so consider this question dead.

Comment: @JaredB It is acceptable to both post and accept your own answer... otherwise you can flag it for deletion.

Comment: @JonathanLeonard sorry for the delay, wasn't able to access computer. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who requested for the link, and for the future peoples who might need it:
http://www.david-gouveia.com/creating-a-basic-synth-in-xna-part-i/

He first goes through the dynamic sound instance, then goes to another level by showing you how to create voices (allowing a sort of 'play piano with your keyboard' type thing).

Funny thing is, David Gouveia has a StackExchange account, so I wouldn't be surprised if I get any notification from him at all, nor if some people recognized him.

Comment: Glad the article helped :) I'm usually at the Game Development Stackexchange, which is why I did not notice this question earlier.