# How to convert mp3 stream to wav stream in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mp3, wav

Lately I've been doing some research on how to play music in silverlight application, and this is the situation I face right now:

(1) I can use `MediaElement`, but it can only play one music file at a time, due to I couldn't use usercontrols in my project, this may not be the solution.

(2) I can use [SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx), but it only supports wav files which are pretty huge even at medium quality.

Since I want to play multiple music files at the same time and control whether to loop it, I think the latter one may be my solution.

I don't put a music file in my project(So the `Load<Song>` Function won't work for me), instead, I put them in the database, after I get all the bytes then I can play it, below is the snippet of the codes:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
SoundEffectInstance soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
if (loopValue.Number == 1.0) soundInstance.IsLooped = true;
soundInstance.Play();
```

This works well with wav file, but if it throws exception when i use it to play mp3 file:

```
System.Exception: 对 COM 组件的调用返回了错误 HRESULT E_FAIL。
位于 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
位于 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.XcpImports.SoundEffect_LoadWavFromStream(SoundEffect soundEffect, Stream stream)
位于 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.FromStream(Stream stream)
....
```

I've not found any library which can directly convert mp3 to wav in silverlight platform, I am not so aware of the inside of SoundEffect, so is anyone who can tell me how to convert mp3 byte stream to wav, so SoundEffect can works ?

btw, due to performance issue, I wouldn't use wcf service to send bytes, and convert them in the hosted web application, it'll adds much pressure on my server, so library like [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) may not help.

So, any great soluton to this puzzle, I would appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at [NLayer](https://nlayer.codeplex.com/) for getting the raw audio data from an MP3.  I would recommend using a DynamicSoundEffectInstance (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037341/1647114)) to output the audio directly (without going through a WAV format stream).

Disclaimer: I am a major contributer to NLayer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but NLayer has almost no documentation and I am new to it, so do you have some demos or blogs that can show me how to use it ?

Comment: Not really... The key is the MpegFile class.  Call the ReadSamples(float[], int, int) method to gather samples.  If you need to seek, set Time to where you want to seek to (you can also use the Position property but it is in bytes).

Comment: I use ReadSamples to gather samples of mp3 bytes:

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content);
MpegFile file = new MpegFile(stream);
int result = file.ReadSamples(content, 0, content.Length);

when I check the content after ReadSamples, I couldn't find the result matches any section of the binary data(use notepad to open mp3).

Could you tell me why? and how to reorganize the sample data.

Comment: You're not going to find it in the MP3 file...  MP3 is a *compressed* format, so you won't find the actual raw audio data in the file.  ReadSamples returns the *uncompressed* audio data, which can then be processed and/or output as desired the same way as any other raw audio data.  Please note that the byte[] overload of ReadSamples is harder to work with... Try using the float[] overload instead.